# Safe use of Enum valueOf for String comparison on a switch

Tags: java, enums

How to safe implement the use of valueOf in case i get a String different than the supported on the enum `ACTION`. I mean is possible to force to `ACTION.valueOf(valueToCompare)` to get a valid value even when happens that `valueToCompare` is not a valid enum member

I get an expected execution when `valueToCompare` is `"CRY"` or `"CRYALOT"` or `"cryalot"` etc.

And i get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` on cases like in the code.

```
public enum ACTION{
    CRY,
    CRYALOT;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String valueTocompare = "posible not expected value".toUpperCase();

    switch (ACTION.valueOf(valueToCompare)) {
        case CRY:
            System.out.println("Cry");
            break;
        case CRYALOT:
            System.out.println("Cry a lot");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("catch posible not expected value");
            break;
    }
}
```

EDIT & used SOLUTION:

I solved this by using a try-catch as @Peter Lawrey suggested:

```
public enum ACTION{
    CRY,
    CRYALOT,
    NOTVALID;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String valueToCompare = "NOTVALID";
    ACTION action;
    try {
        valueToCompare= "variable posible not expected value".toUpperCase();
        action = ACTION.valueOf(valueToCompare);
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        System.out.println("Handled glitch on the Matrix");
        action = ACTION.NOTVALID;
    }

    switch (action) {
        case CRY:
            System.out.println("Cry");
            break;
        case CRYALOT:
            System.out.println("Cry a lot");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("catch posible not expected value");
            break;
    }

    System.out.println("We continue normal execution on main thread...");
}
```

Comment: Because `ACTION.valueOf("cryalot")` is as much invalid as `Integer.valueOf("ghj")`. You can either try to call `String.toUpperCase()` or try/catch the IllegalArgumentException if you cannot guarantee that the input always corresponds to an enum value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to catch the IllegalArgumentException

```
try {
    switch (ACTION.valueOf(valueToCompare)) {

    }
} catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
    // unknown
}
```

Or you can create your own function which does this.

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> E valueOf(E defaultValue, String s) {
    try {
        return Enum.valueOf(defaultValue.getDeclaringClass(), s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Note: `switch(null)` throws a `NullPointerException` rather than branching to `default:`

Comment: I guess that the try catch is the best approach. Or instead of the enum i could just used constant like `static final String CRY = "cry";` But in terms of computing efficiency which one could be more suitable? May be is a question beyond the solution, but still curious.

Comment: @Xaren you can add an enum value like UNKNOWN. The fastest solution is to switch on the String without converting to an enum.

Answer (score 6):

Using exceptions for flow control is considered as a bad practice.

```
    String valueToCompare = value.toUpperCase();

    ACTION action = Arrays.stream(ACTION.values())
       .filter(a -> a.name().equals(valueToCompare)).findFirst().orElse(ACTION.NOTVALID);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

the problem here is this line:
`ACTION.valueOf(valueToCompare)` - you are trying to run `valueOf` on `valueToCompare`, and its erroring out since the value isn't an enum in `ACTION`. It's not even making the switch statement to print out the default msg.

Have a look at the changes I've done, you'll notice a few things, the main one being actionToCompare...

```
    enum Action {
      CRY,
      CRYALOT,
      EXAMPLE
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Action actionToCompare = Action.EXAMPLE;
    switch (actionToCompare) {
      case CRY:
        System.out.println("Cry");
        break;
      case CRYALOT:
        System.out.println("Cry a lot");
        break;
      default:
        System.out.println("catch posible not expected value");
        break;
    }
  }
```

if you insist on using a `String` over converting it to the enum `Action`, wrap it in a `try...catch` statement so if an invalid string is passed in it can handle the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can always build yourself a reverse-lookup.

```
enum Action {
    CRY,
    CRYALOT,
    EXAMPLE;

    // Lookup map for actions in string form.
    static Map<String,Action> lookup = Arrays.stream(values()).collect(Collectors.toMap(
            // Key is name in lowercase.
            a -> a.name().toLowerCase(),
            // Value is the Action.
            a -> a));

    public static Action lookup(String name) {
        return lookup.get(name.toLowerCase());
    }
}

public void test() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(Action.lookup("cry"));
    System.out.println(Action.lookup("CryAlot"));
}
```

Comment: What's the point of your `lookup` map? `valueOf` does the same thing. If all the constants are upper case and you want to lookup ignoring case just do `valueOf(name.toUpperCase())` in your lookup method.

Comment: @Oleg - 1. It does not throw an exception if not found. 2. It can handle enums in any case ( I don't use enums in uppercase, I use camelcase).

Comment: 1. It will return null and OP's code will just throw a different exception. 2. OP's code(and most code) use upper case. Lookup maps for Enums are definitely useful in many cases, just not in this one.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that does not involve exceptions in the control flow and enables mapping the enum name or the action name to the action with a default behavior in case there is no mapping entry:

```
public enum CryActions {
    CRY_A_LITTLE("Cry a little", CryALittleActionHandler::new), CRY_A_LOT("Cry a lot", CryALotActionHandler::new), DEFAULT("Default", DefaultCryActionHandler::new);

    private String actionName;
    private Supplier<CryActionHandler> supplier;

    private CryActions(String actionName, Supplier<CryActionHandler> supplier) {
        this.actionName = actionName;
        this.supplier = supplier;
        PossibleCryActions.byEnumName.put(name(), this);
        PossibleCryActions.byActionName.put(actionName, this);
    }

    public void handleAction() {
        supplier.get().handleAction();
    }

    public String getActionName() {
        return actionName;
    }

    public static CryActions fromEnumName(String enumName) {
        return PossibleCryActions.byEnumName.computeIfAbsent(enumName, x -> DEFAULT);
    }

    public static CryActions fromActionName(String actionName) {
        return PossibleCryActions.byActionName.computeIfAbsent(actionName, x -> DEFAULT);
    }

    private static class PossibleCryActions {
        private static Map<String, CryActions> byEnumName = new HashMap<>();
        private static Map<String, CryActions> byActionName = new HashMap<>();
    }
}

public interface CryActionHandler {
    void handleAction();
}

public class CryALittleActionHandler implements CryActionHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleAction() {
        System.out.println("Just crying a little...");
    }
}

public class CryALotActionHandler implements CryActionHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleAction() {
        System.out.println("Crying a river...");
    }
}

public class DefaultCryActionHandler implements CryActionHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleAction() {
        System.out.println("Just crying as default behavior...");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CryActions.fromEnumName("CRY_A_LITTLE").handleAction();
        CryActions.fromEnumName("CRY_A_LOT").handleAction();
        CryActions.fromEnumName("CRY_UNEXPECTEDLY").handleAction();
        CryActions.fromActionName("Cry a little").handleAction();
        CryActions.fromActionName("Cry a lot").handleAction();
        CryActions.fromActionName("Cry unexpectedly").handleAction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin** version:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> safeValueOf(name: String, defaultValue: T): T =
try {
    java.lang.Enum.valueOf(T::class.java, name) ?: defaultValue
} catch(e: IllegalArgumentException) {
    defaultValue
}
```